# How to use DataRowState.Deleted?

Tags: c#, datatables, rowstate

I have a delete button which removes items from the DataGridVeiw and sets the main DataTable.Row.RowState to Deleted. Problem arises when I want to save all changes but can no longer access the a value (ID) from the row which state has changed. Ill show you the code:

```
    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvProducts.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            foreach(DataRow row in mIOptions.mProductsOnList.Rows)
            {
                if (dgvProducts.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value == row[2] && txtProdCode.Text == row[1].ToString())
                {
                    dgvProducts.Rows.Remove(dgvProducts.CurrentRow);
                    row.Delete();
                    break;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
```

Now the Check:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in mIOptions.mProductsOnList.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            {
                mPresenterOptions.UpdateProduct(row);
            }
            else if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
            {
                mPresenterOptions.SaveProduct(row);
            }
            else if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
            {
                mPresenterOptions.DeleteProduct(row); // *row no longer contains the ID (needed to delete from db)*
            }
        }

        mIOptions.mProductsOnList.AcceptChanges();
```

So what is the normal work-around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your replecationg the methode.
[.AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
use

```
foreach(DataRow oRow in  mIOptions.mProductsOnList.Where(x.Rowstate = DataRowState.Deleted))
{
 var rowid = oRow["ColumName", DataRowVersion.Original];
//delete row from database
}
mIOptions.mProductsOnList.AcceptChanges()
```

to accept all deletions/updates/adds

Comment: I have that line after the check as doing it before hand will reset all the states. Its the delete state which is causing issues as I simply need to know the ID of that record so I can delete from database..

Comment: updated the code with a linq expresion witch gives you the rows witch will be deleted but normaly you atatch the database to a dataset. when u update this dataset the database gets updated 2.

Comment: I would bind normally, but the dgv takes values from multiple database tables so binding to one is not possible here. Ill try your code in a bit but I thinking your doing the same thing and: var rowid = oRow["IdColumnName"]; will give you the same error..

Comment: what exception do you get while retrieving the id using when row["columnName"] in your initial example?

Comment: System.Data.DeletedRowInaccessibleException
"Deleted row information cannot be accessed through the row."

Comment: Think one solution is just to create an integer array of deleted ID numbers before I do the row.Delete(); then run through the array and delete them all that way. But I do not see the point in DataRowState.Deleted? If i wanted to remove the row so the data is inaccessible I would have used row.remove..

Comment: could you try getting the id with this param
row["CustomerID", DataRowVersion.Original]

Comment: Excellent, mPresenterOptions.DeleteProduct(Convert.ToInt32(row[0, DataRowVersion.Original])); Does the job and your answer too will now work thanks to this DataRowVersion attribute :D